# %cython with Anaconda distribution on Windows LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, windows, gcc, cython, jupyter-notebook

I've seen similar answers to this error but mine is a LinkError so I assume it might be a bit different to solve. On top of that the answers to all these errors that appear to be similar are different.

I am trying to use cython via the ipython notebook:

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython
cdef double f_typed(double x):
    return x * (x - 1)
cpdef double integrate_f_typed(double a, double b, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double s, dx
    s = 0
    dx = (b - a) / N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f_typed(a + i * dx)
    return s * dx
```

but it seems that maybe something isn't linked properly given the error... Not sure where to look or what to do.

Here is the error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinkError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b9b32dd293fb> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'cython', u'', u'cdef double f_typed(double x):\n    return x * (x - 1)\ncpdef double integrate_f_typed(double a, double b, int N):\n    cdef int i\n    cdef double s, dx\n    s = 0\n    dx = (b - a) / N\n    for i in range(N):\n        s += f_typed(a + i * dx)\n    return s * dx')

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2160             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2161             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2162                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2163             return result
   2164 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)
    266             build_extension.build_temp = os.path.dirname(pyx_file)
    267             build_extension.build_lib  = lib_dir
--> 268             build_extension.run()
    269             self._code_cache[key] = module_name
    270 

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.pyc in run(self)
    337 
    338         # Now actually compile and link everything.
--> 339         self.build_extensions()
    340 
    341     def check_extensions_list(self, extensions):

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.pyc in build_extensions(self)
    446 
    447         for ext in self.extensions:
--> 448             self.build_extension(ext)
    449 
    450     def build_extension(self, ext):

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.pyc in build_extension(self, ext)
    528             debug=self.debug,
    529             build_temp=self.build_temp,
--> 530             target_lang=language)
    531 
    532 

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\ccompiler.pyc in link_shared_object(self, objects, output_filename, output_dir, libraries, library_dirs, runtime_library_dirs, export_symbols, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
    689                   libraries, library_dirs, runtime_library_dirs,
    690                   export_symbols, debug,
--> 691                   extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
    692 
    693     def link_executable(self, objects, output_progname, output_dir=None,

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.pyc in link(self, target_desc, objects, output_filename, output_dir, libraries, library_dirs, runtime_library_dirs, export_symbols, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
    258                            extra_postargs,
    259                            build_temp,
--> 260                            target_lang)
    261 
    262     # link ()

C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\unixccompiler.pyc in link(self, target_desc, objects, output_filename, output_dir, libraries, library_dirs, runtime_library_dirs, export_symbols, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
    198                 self.spawn(linker + ld_args)
    199             except DistutilsExecError, msg:
--> 200                 raise LinkError, msg
    201         else:
    202             log.debug("skipping %s (up-to-date)", output_filename)

LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using:
Cython 0.20 and gcc 4.7 (Installed with Anaconda python distribution) with Python 2.7.5 on Windows 7

Comment: What output do you see in the terminal window where you started the IPython notebook? Output from the compiler is often redirected there.

Comment: I just found out yesterday that the issue was related to installing mingw separately when it was already included in the Anaconda distribution. All I did was reinstall Anaconda and everything worked great